# In OpenGL 3.3, is there any more efficient and correct way of drawing a point?

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

I intend to draw points that usually only change the position on the screen.

The color and size do not usually vary.

So I did this class `Point` in Python:

```py
class Point2D():
    _verts = None
    _vshader_code = '''
        #version 330

        in vec2 pos;

        uniform float size;

        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0.0, 1.0);
            gl_PointSize = size;
        }
    '''
    _fshader_code = '''
        #version 330

        uniform vec4 col;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = col;
        }
    '''

    def __init__(self, size, col):
        ## CREATE PROGRAM/SHADER ##
        self.program = GL.glCreateProgram()

        self.shaders = [
            CreateShader(self._vshader_code, GL.GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
            CreateShader(self._fshader_code, GL.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        ]

        for shader in self.shaders:
            GL.glAttachShader(self.program, shader)

        GL.glLinkProgram(self.program)
        #CheckShaderError(self.program, GL.GL_LINK_STATUS, True, "Error: Program linking failed:")
        GL.glValidateProgram(self.program)
        #CheckShaderError(self.program, GL.GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, True, "Error: Program is invalid:")

        self.unif_size = GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'size')
        self.unif_col = GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'col')

        GL.glUseProgram(self.program)
        GL.glUniform1f(self.unif_size, size)
        GL.glUniform4fv(self.unif_col, 1, col)

        ## FLAGS ##
        #GL.glEnable(GL.GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
        GL.glEnable(GL.GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE)

    def bind_array(self, array):
        self._verts = array

        ## BIND BUFFER ##
        self.vertexArrayObject = GL.glGenVertexArrays(1)
        GL.glBindVertexArray(self.vertexArrayObject)

        self.buff = GL.glGenBuffers(1)
        GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buff)
    
        GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._verts.nbytes, self._verts, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        self.attr_pos = GL.glGetAttribLocation(self.program, 'pos')

        GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        GL.glVertexAttribPointer(self.attr_pos, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, GL.GL_FALSE, 8, None)

        GL.glBindVertexArray(0)

    def update_size_and_color(self, size, col):
        #GL.glPointSize(size)
        GL.glUseProgram(self.program)
    
        GL.glUniform1f(self.unif_size, size)
        GL.glUniform4fv(self.unif_col, 1, col)

    def update_elem(self, index, value):
        GL.glUseProgram(self.program)

        self._verts[index] = value
        GL.glBindVertexArray(self.vertexArrayObject)
        GL.glBufferSubData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, index * 8, 8, value)
        GL.glBindVertexArray(0)

    def Draw(self):
        GL.glUseProgram(self.program)

        GL.glBindVertexArray(self.vertexArrayObject)
        GL.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_POINTS, 0, len(self._verts))
        GL.glBindVertexArray(0)

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            #if the context is alive, you want to try and delete shader/program stuff manually
            #this could be triggered with e.g. `del Display`
            for shader in self.shaders:
                GL.glDetachShader(self.program, shader)
                GL.glDeleteShader(shader)
            GL.glDeleteProgram(self.program)
        except OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError as error:
            print("context already deleted my shader/program stuff!")

        GL.glDisable(GL.GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE)
```

With the created point object, I can do the point drawing as follows:

```py
point = Point2D(10.0, numpy.array((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 'f4'))
point.bind_array(numpy.zeros((2, 2), 'f4'))

## DRAW ##
point.update_elem(0, numpy.array((0.5, 0.0), 'f4'))
point.update_elem(1, numpy.array((-0.5, 0.0), 'f4'))
point.Draw()
(...code...)
point.update_elem(1, numpy.array((0.25, 0.25), 'f4'))
point.Draw()
```

The drawing is practical and seemingly efficient, but the question is am I doing it right?

Answer (score 3):

The way you're doing it will work and is reasonable. If you're drawing lots of points (thousands to millions), you might want to make a single array with all the coordinates and another array with the vertex attributes for all the points and issue a single draw call with those arrays. That will reduce the number of draw calls, which can be a performance limiting factor. But if you're only drawing a few dozen to maybe a few hundred, you probably won't notice a huge difference. As always, it pays to profile your code and see where the slowdowns are rather than guessing.

Comment: Good idea, I'll edit the code, change uniform by attribute and put a fuction that takes an array with all the coordinates of the different points, to draw one or several

Answer (score 1):

You should use [instanced](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArraysInstanced.xhtml) drawing. Load only one model of your point as a static data, and use array of positions (any other attributes) for those objects.

There is many tutorials about this method. Here is [one](https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing) for example.